# For loop error in C

Tags: c, for-loop, wordsearch

I have been working for so long on this code and I just can't figure it out!
The aim of this code is to create a word search game. However, I have split the functions which it is to do in small parts so that they can become more manageable. In the following code, the program is supposed to output the top row of the word search which is supposed to show the letters from A to J, as well as the left column which shows the numbers from 0 to 9. The program is also meant to output the 4 random hidden words (which the user is supposed to find during the game) at RANDOM positions. I have tried to do this by checking whether a particular location within the array is equal to NULL, and if it is NULL the random word should be outputted in that position. However, nothing is being outputted on screen for some reason.

This is my code so far:

```
char getRandomCharacter();
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char getRandomCharacter(){
    int r = (rand() % 26) + 65;
    return (char)r;
}

int main(void){

    int randomNum;
    int rand2;
    char* wordSearch[10][10]={NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
                            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    const char *takenWords[4];
    const char *words[20]={"DOG", "CAT", "ELEPHANT", "CROCODILE", "HIPPOPOTAMUS", "TORTOISE", "TIGER", "FISH", "SEAGULL", "SEAL", "MONKEY", "KANGAROO", "ZEBRA", "GIRAFFE", "RABBIT", "HORSE", "PENGUIN", "BEAR", "SQUIRREL", "HAMSTER"};


    printf("\n\tA\t\tB\t\tC\t\tD\t\tE\t\tF\t\tG\t\tH\t\tI\t\tJ\n");
    for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
        printf("\n%d\t", i-1);

            for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
                do{
                srand(time(NULL));
                rand2=(rand()%10);
                if(&wordSearch[rand2]==NULL){
                    int flag=0;
                    do{
                        randomNum = (rand()%20);
                        takenWords[i]=words[randomNum];
                        flag=0;
                        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                            if(strcmp(words[randomNum],takenWords[j])==0)flag=1;
                        }
                    }while(flag);
                    printf("%s\n", words[randomNum]);
                }
                }while(&wordSearch[rand2]==NULL);
            }
        printf("\n\n");
    }
        /*for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            char c=getRandomCharacter();
            wordSearch[i][j]=c;
            printf("%c\t\t", *(&(wordSearch[i][j])));
        }*/

        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you define the second `i` loop `for(int i=0; i<4; i++)` the `i` in the outer loop is still in scope

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
while(&wordSearch[rand2]==NULL);
```

must be wrong. The address of an element inside an array will never be `NULL`. You probably meant it without the `&`, but that doesn't make sense either since `wordSearch` is a 2D array ...

Comment: I fixed it as you said..But this resulted in an infinite loop which only displayed the same word over and over again